# The meaning of last here in the sentence

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases

> We watched the *last* of the runners come in.

Can this mean two things?
the last runner or the runners who came in towards the end of the race?

Answer (score 1):

While it would be possible for this to mean watching the final runner arrive at the finish, generally speaking, *to watch the last of [something]* means to watch the final group of things until the very end.  In a race, perhaps there is a pack of racers near the end, or a few stragglers behind the rest of the runners, they would be the last of the runners, maybe the final 5-10%.

Note that there is also an idiom, *to see/hear the last of [someone]* which has a different meaning entirely.  It is an expression used when you want to state that you will never see a person again (and usually to express that you are glad about that fact.)  Basically it means that you've seen, or hope you've seen, someone for the last time ever.

Comment: I agree. If this was referring to one runner only, the better way to say it is, "We watched the last runner come in."